# Generar Combinaciones sin Repetir

Tags: python, python-3.x

Es algo muy básico, no tengo muchos conocimientos

digamos que quiero imprimir los posibles Resultados de un partido

Por ejemplo Real Madrid - Barcelona

y las posibilidades de goles de cada equipo son desde 0 a 9

como seria para que imprima todos los resultados posibles sin repetir

```
Real Madrid 0 - Barcelona 0
```

```
Real Madrid 1 - Barcelona 0
```

```
Real Madrid 0 - Barcelona 1
```

Etc..

Comment: .....1-Y ¿Nos enseñas tu intento?.2-Te recomiendo que uses una lista, el modulo random y lo confirme si el numero aparece en la lista con un if x in list: #Si esta se vuelve a sacar otro numero si no se almacena.

Comment: Con dos `for` anidados.

Answer (score 2):

Se puede hacer con dos for anidados:

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        print("Real Madrid " + str(i) + "- Barcelona " + str(j))
```